# Откуда берутся значения функции

Tags: javascript, функции

Не пойму, как так получается, что значением аргумента year становятся значения переменных carYear и personYear? Распишите пошагово, пожалуйста.

```
let carYear = 2010,
    personYear = 1989;

function calculateAge(year) {
    let currentYear = 2019,
        result = currentYear - year;
        return result; }

function checkAndLogAge(year) {
    if (calculateAge(year) < 10) {
        console.log('Возраст меньше 10 лет');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Возраст больше 10 лет');
    } }

checkAndLogAge(carYear);
checkAndLogAge(personYear);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пошагово:

1. Вы вызываете функцию `checkAndLogAge` с действительным параметром `carYear`, значение которого `2010`.  Значение формального параметра `year` внутри функции в этом вызове становится равным `2010`.
2. Вы вызываете функцию `checkAndLogAge` с действительным параметром `personYear`, значение которого `1989`.  Значение формального параметра `year` внутри функции в этом вызове становится равным `1989`.